# Why i obtain this exception when I try to add an object to a list? (EX: Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

Tags: c#, .net, list, exception

I have the following situation. In a method I have the following code:

```
XmlNodeList n_vulnerablesystemslist = n_alertdocument.SelectNodes(
    "./x:VulnerableSystems/x:VulnerableSystem", nsmgr);

foreach (XmlNode n_vulnerablesystem in n_vulnerablesystemslist)
{
    DataModel.Vulnerability.VulnerableSystem currentVulnerableSystem = 
        new DataModel.Vulnerability.VulnerableSystem();

    currentVulnerableSystem.Title = 
        n_vulnerablesystem.SelectSingleNode("./x:Title", nsmgr) == null 
        ? "" 
        : n_vulnerablesystem.SelectSingleNode("./x:Title", nsmgr).InnerText;
    currentDeepSightVuln.VulnerabilityVulnerableSystems.Add(
        currentVulnerableSystem);
}
```

Where **VulnerabilityVulnerableSystems** is the following collection definied inside the **Vuln currentDeepSightVuln** object:

```
public virtual List<VulnerableSystem> VulnerabilityVulnerableSystems
    { get; set; }
```

The problem is that when try to execute the **Add** operation the following exception is thrown:

> - ex {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
>         System.Exception {System.NullReferenceException}

This seems to me very strange because, in the debugger I can see that the **VulnerableSystem currentVulnerableSystem** object is initialized and that its **Title** is correctly valorized.

So what is the problem? What am I missing? How can I solve it?

Tnx

Comment: Well is anything ever setting `VulnerabilityVulnerableSystems` to a non-null value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the List `VulnerabilityVulnerableSystems` has not been initialized. So the Add method operates on a Null reference.

Try `VulnerabilityVulnerableSystems = new List<VulnerableSystem>();`